# Flash CS5 - Stage Size Limitation?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, size, stage

i've created large vector graphics in Illustrator to be imported in Flash as display assets.

the application i'm building will target different screen sizes (including Television with AIR 2.5) and the display assets will be scaled down at runtime to fit the target screen.

the largest of vector graphic imports is 5000 x 1250 pixels.  however, i can't import the graphic (either as a native vector or a bitmap conversion) because of the stage size limitation in Flash Professional CS5:

[image]

from the flash.display.BitmapData class documentation:

> In AIR 1.5 and Flash Player 10, the
>   maximum size for a BitmapData object
>   is 8,191 pixels in width or height,
>   and the total number of pixels cannot
>   exceed 16,777,215 pixels. (So, if a
>   BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels
>   wide, it can only be 2,048 pixels
>   high.) In Flash Player 9 and earlier
>   and AIR 1.1 and earlier, the
>   limitation is 2,880 pixels in height
>   and 2,880 in width.

i'm targeting Air 2.5 for the Publish Settings Player and i still can not increase the stage size above 2880 x 2880 or import graphics larger than 2880 x 2880.

if the BitmapData limitation has been increased for Flash Player 10 and AIR 1.5 or higher, why can't i import graphics and/or increase the size of the stage within that limit?

Comment: while this doesn't solve your question, it is generally a bad idea to assign filters to illustrator assets you plan on porting to flash. In fact I try to get everyone to do as much as possible in flash at the office. I'm sure in upcoming versions of the Creative Suite the products will be more and more compatible, but right now AI->Fl still requires a lot of extra work. So remove all your bitmap filters, and recreate them as vectors in flash if you can. Aside from the headache, do you really need an app with many megs of bloat stemming from a filter?

Comment: sure, that's smart advice.  i only have one bitmap filter, which is Photoshop Effects > Texture > Grain and that's not possible to create in Flash, or at least not with ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash CS5 will need to be updated so that it will accept the new larger stage sizes, however, there is no information about when such an update will be available.

On the other hand, since your asset is vector graphic, why not just import it at a smaller size, it'll be the same.

Comment: a few of my assets have bitmap filter effects that aren't scaleable.  Flash player 10 was release in October 2008, are they really going to ever update Flash Professional to take advantage of the larger sizes?  i feel like reporting this as a bug.

Comment: Have a look at the Adobe Flash forums, I would recommend you do report this issue (if it's not already be done), it's legitimate.

Comment: i don't believe it's just Flash CS5 but a limitation with the player.  setting the meta data tag doesn't work either:[SWF(width="2881", height="2881", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#000000")]

Comment: The meta-tag isn't read by the flash player, it's used by the compiler.

Comment: i've reported the bug to adobe.